# Pass value into a view using block input

Tags: views, blocks, 9

I have created a Drupal 9 site with articles that belongs to taxonomy terms. I want to give the ability to the administrator of the site to place a block with whatever taxonomy he wants.

How would I set up the block configuration with a drop-down of the taxonomy terms and pass the selected values to the Drupal views and filter based on the selected taxonomy terms?

In the block settings there is not any option to pass the filter to the block.

[image: drupal views]

[image: block settings]

Any Idea on this using existing module or with custom code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not answering directly, because I don't know if you could do this with a configurable Views block without custom code.

A different approach only using UI would be on entity level, creating a block type containing two fields, the taxonomy drop-down and an EVA field passing the other field's value via a token. The site admin has then to use the *Custom Block Library* to create a custom block for this block type.

Add the EVA field to the block type with this module: https://www.drupal.org/project/eva

Comment: thanks for your answer. it would be nice if you also give me some details about the way using configurable Views block with custom code.

Comment: I would start with a block plugin from scratch, add the taxonomy drop-down to the block config form and [views_embed_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.module/function/views_embed_view/9.1.x) the view to the block build providing the term as argument.

Comment: After pass the term as an argument to `views_embed_view`, how can I filter the results with this argument and render this view to the block?

Comment: Add an *Embed* display to your View and add a contextual filter for the argument.

Comment: How to I map the `tid` of the selected taxonomy terms that I I pass as an argument with the contextual filter from the view?

Comment: The contextual filter has the option **Multiple arguments** - One or more IDs separated by , or +

Comment: Thank you very much. It works like a charm :)

Comment: I have one more issue. When I place the block to the same region more than 1 times only the latest is presented in the frontend theme. Do you know why?

Comment: No, just tried to place a custom block plugin of my own two times in the same region and they both appear on the front page. Is this even connected to the view, does it work if you don't output the view and only the selected terms (for debugging purpose)? If you found out more details I think it's worth starting a new question.

Comment: the issue is about context https://www.drupal.org/project/context When I place the block without the context is working.

Comment: Since this module is still in beta you can support develeopment and post an issue if you have a reproducible example code.

Comment: okay. Thank you!

Comment: In the block config form there is an option "Unique" that let you place same block multiple times. https://www.drupal.org/project/context/issues/3207194

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar requirement on a previous project with Layout Builder: We used a `block_content` entity. We are using the [Block field module](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_field) to create a `field_view` containing a reference to the views block.

Every other field on the custom block content entity basically was a faked Views UI: Every filter that we wanted to expose to the editors, was created as field on the block_content (mostly taxonomy term references), and then mapped to views exposed filters in a special field formatter widget for the block field.

It is a bit of hack, but our editors were quite happy with it. The field formatter below is tailored to our specfic needs, but might help to get some ideas.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\wt_dgm\Plugin\Field\FieldFormatter;

use Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\ContextException;
use Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheableMetadata;
use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemListInterface;
use Drupal\block_field\Plugin\Field\FieldFormatter\BlockFieldFormatter;
use Drupal\Core\Plugin\ContextAwarePluginInterface;
use Drupal\views\Element\View;
use Drupal\views\Plugin\Block\ViewsBlock;

/**
 * Plugin implementation of the 'block_field' formatter.
 *
 * @FieldFormatter(
 *   id = "autolist_blockfield",
 *   label = @Translation("Block field with filters from Auto-List block"),
 *   field_types = {
 *     "block_field"
 *   }
 * )
 */
class AutoListBlockField extends BlockFieldFormatter {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function viewElements(FieldItemListInterface $items, $langcode) {
    /** @var $parentEntity \Drupal\block_content\Entity\BlockContent */
    $parentEntity = $items->getEntity();
    if ($parentEntity->getEntityTypeId() != 'block_content' || $items->getFieldDefinition()->getName() != 'field_view') {
      return parent::viewElements($items, $langcode);
    }

    $elements = [];
    foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
      /** @var \Drupal\block_field\BlockFieldItemInterface $item */
      $block = $item->getBlock();

      if (!($block instanceof ViewsBlock)) {
        continue;
      }

      // copy & paste parent::viewElements()
      if ($block instanceof ContextAwarePluginInterface) {
        try {
          $contexts = \Drupal::service('context.repository')->getRuntimeContexts($block->getContextMapping());
          \Drupal::service('context.handler')->applyContextMapping($block, $contexts);
        }
        catch (ContextException $e) {
          continue;
        }
      }
      if (!$block || !$block->access(\Drupal::currentUser())) {
        continue;
      }

      // apply my custom filters and sort options to the views block
      $view = $block->getViewExecutable();
      $display = $view->current_display;

      $args = [$parentEntity->id()];
      $view->setArguments([$parentEntity->id()]);

      $filters = [];

      /* ### alter views filter ### */
      if ($parentEntity->hasField('field_contentypes')) {
        $filters['type'] = array_column($parentEntity->get('field_contentypes')->getValue(), 'value');
      }
      foreach ($parentEntity->getFields() as $fieldName => $field) {
        if ($field->getFieldDefinition()->getType() == 'entity_reference' && $field->getFieldDefinition()->getSetting('target_type') == 'taxonomy_term') {
          if (!$field->isEmpty()) {
            $filters[$fieldName . '_target_id'] = array_column($field->getValue(), 'target_id');
          }
        }
      }
      /* ### alter views sort ### */
      $sort = $parentEntity->get('field_sort')->value;
      $filters['sort_by'] = $sort;
      $view->setExposedInput($filters);

      $view->setItemsPerPage($parentEntity->get('field_quantity')->value);

      $view->display_handler->setOption('title', $parentEntity->get('field_title')->value);

      //@see \Drupal\views\Plugin\Block\ViewsBlock::build()
      $output = $view->buildRenderable($display, $args, FALSE);
      $output = View::preRenderViewElement($output);

      $elements[$delta] = $output;

      CacheableMetadata::createFromRenderArray($elements[$delta])
        ->addCacheableDependency($parentEntity)
        ->applyTo($elements[$delta]);
    }
    return $elements;
  }

}
```

PS: Ajax has to be enabled on the views block, otherwise setting `$filter` did not work correctly for us.

Answer (score 0):

This module does exactly what you're looking for, though it has no stable release. It looks relatively easy to adapt to Drupal 9/10/11. The functionality is contained in a single block plugin class.

https://www.drupal.org/project/oveo